# I can't upload codes to my ESP8266

Tags: esp8266, upload

[[image: This is the error it gives],this is the error I encounter when i try to upload my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CB9NX.jpg)

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFiMulti.h>

#ifndef STASSID
#define STASSID "your-ssid"
#define STAPSK  "your-password"
#endif

const char* ssid     = STASSID;
const char* password = STAPSK;

const char* host = "192.168.1.1";
const uint16_t port = 3000;

ESP8266WiFiMulti WiFiMulti;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  // We start by connecting to a WiFi network
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFiMulti.addAP(ssid, password);

  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Wait for WiFi... ");

  while (WiFiMulti.run() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(500);
  }

  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  delay(500);
}


void loop() {
  Serial.print("connecting to ");
  Serial.print(host);
  Serial.print(':');
  Serial.println(port);

  // Use WiFiClient class to create TCP connections
  WiFiClient client;

  if (!client.connect(host, port)) {
    Serial.println("connection failed");
    Serial.println("wait 5 sec...");
    delay(5000);
    return;
  }

  // This will send the request to the server
  client.println("hello from ESP8266");

  //read back one line from server
  Serial.println("receiving from remote server");
  String line = client.readStringUntil('\r');
  Serial.println(line);

  Serial.println("closing connection");
  client.stop();

  Serial.println("wait 5 sec...");
  delay(5000);
}
```

Comment: Need a bit more information, what ESP8266 module are you using? Does it have a Reset swtich that needs to be held to program? Like discussed at this link... https://tttapa.github.io/ESP8266/Chap06%20-%20Uploading.html#:~:text=press%20and%20hold%20the%20reset,will%20boot%20in%20program%20mode

Comment: why are you posting a picture of text? ... you pasted the code, paste the error message also ... if you can't upload then the code is irrelevant and only clutters up the post

Comment: Which version of arduino IDE do you use? Try to update

Answer (score 1):

Try updating the Serial Driver in your system or try using lesser baud rate, i.e. 9600 instead of 115200.

Comment: You should be able to program an ESP8266 at 500Kbit/s or faster. If it only programs at 9600, something's not right.